# Converting the image files to each other

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I'm trying to make a code which converts the image files to each other and I succeeded also but I have a problem. I use a jpg file for test and when I convert it to an icon with the help of my program, I can do it, I have the .ico file on my desktop, everything is fine until now. But then I try to use the .ico file as the icon of my form for test and it gives "Argument 'picture' must be a picture that can be used as a Icon" error. Should I write a special code for converting the files or is it just for .ico files? If so, how can i solve this? Thanks for helping :)

Here's my entire code(also I'm doing this just for practice so if you want to use some part or all of the code, you can):

```
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);

    #region ConvertFile
    void ConvertFile(string a, ImageFormat b, string c)
    {
        Image d = Image.FromFile(c);
        Bitmap e = new Bitmap(d);
        e.Save(path + @"\ConvertedImage." + a, b);
        MessageBox.Show(
            "Image has been successfully converted! You can find it on your desktop.");
    } 
    #endregion

    #region Form1_Load
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
    #endregion

    #region btnBrowse_Click
    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = path;
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        txtFolderWay.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        if (txtFolderWay.Text != "")
        {
            try
            {
                Image image = Image.FromFile(txtFolderWay.Text);
                pcbImage.Image = image;
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Choose a proper file type!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
                txtFolderWay.Text = "";
                pcbImage.Image = null;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region btnConvert_Click
    private void btnConvert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a = txtFolderWay.Text;
        #region Error Check
        if (txtFolderWay.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose a path!");
            return;
        } 
        #endregion

        if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Choose a file type!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
            return;
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            ConvertFile("jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 2)
        {
            ConvertFile("png",ImageFormat.Png,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 3)
        {
            ConvertFile("bmp",ImageFormat.Bmp,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 4)
        {
            ConvertFile("emf",ImageFormat.Emf,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 5)
        {
            ConvertFile("exif",ImageFormat.Exif,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 6)
        {
            ConvertFile("gif",ImageFormat.Gif,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 7)
        {
            ConvertFile("ico",ImageFormat.Icon,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 8)
        {
            ConvertFile("bmp",ImageFormat.MemoryBmp,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 9)
        {
            ConvertFile("tiff",ImageFormat.Tiff,a);
        }
        else if (cmbFileTypes.SelectedIndex == 10)
        {
            ConvertFile("wmf",ImageFormat.Wmf,a);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: How do you “use the .ico file as the icon of my form” and what is the “it” that gives the error?

Comment: I meant from the properties tab, when the form is selected, I go to the icon property and set the icon as the file I converted and when I so this, I get the error. My englis is not flawless, sorry :)